# ¿Por qué cuando declaro una estructura con un dato del mismo tipo de la estructura, me da un error en C++?

Tags: c++

Como ejemplo, doy el siguiente caso:

```
struct estructura{ 
   estructura dato; 
};
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa, el compilador me dice lo siguiente:

> field 'dato' has incomplete type 'estructura'

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una clase (o estructura) no se entiende como declarada hasta que el compilador no procesa completamente su interfaz, es decir, hasta que llega al punto y coma:

```
struct estructura // <<--- inicio declaración
{
  // ...
};                // <<--- fin declaración
```

Y el compilador no te va a dejar declarar objetos de una clase hasta que la misma no esté completamente declarada.

**¿Y esto por qué es así?**

Básicamente porque hasta que el compilador no conoce completamente la interfaz de una clase no puede estar seguro acerca de la cantidad de memoria que necesita reservar para almacenar objetos de dicha estructura... un dato básico para que el compilador haga bien su trabajo.

**¿Soluciones?**

Lo que estás intentando hacer es declarar una clase que se contiene a sí misma y esa espiral se repitirá hasta el infinito:

```
struct estructura
{
  struct estructura
  {
    struct estructura
    {
      // ...
    } dato;
  } dato;
};
```

Para que un objeto pueda gestionar otros objetos de su mismo tipo es imprescindible usar punteros:

```
struct estructura
{
  estructura* ptr;
};
```

Puesto que un puntero no es más que una referencia a una posición de memoria, no se producirá el efecto antes comentado.

Otra solución pasa por crear objetos **fuera** de la clase:

```
struct estructura
{
  // ...
};

estructura dato; // Como objeto suelto

struct otra_estructura
{
  estructura dato; // Objeto anidado dentro de otra clase
};
```

Answer (score 5):

> *¿Por qué da error?*

Porque el compilador es incapaz de entender el **tipo de dato** que tiene dentro la estructura pues esta todavia no esta definida, un ejemplo para que se vea mejor:

```
struct struct_perro{ <------------------+
                                        |
    int patas;                          |----- Se usa a si mismo como sin estar definido.
    bool sexo;                          |
    string nombre;                      |
    struct_perro mi_perro_juan; <-------+

};
```

Tenemos la estructura **struct_perro** y un tipo de dato dentro de esa estructura del mismo tipo.

Por tanto cuando el compilador quiera "aprenderse" esa estructura se encuentra con que hay un tipo de dato igual dentro y causa un error

Espero haberte aclarado algo.

Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto, asi te funcionara declarar un dato del mismo tipo de la estructura

```
struct estructura{
   typedef struct estructura dato;
};
```

Comment: Hola Jesus, aunque esta publicación puede resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Intenta añadir una descripción con lo que hace y por qué va a funcionar. Lee [answer] para más información.